# How to remove \" and \r\n from string retrived from database

Tags: c#, string, encoding

I am displaying a message to the user like so:

```
Messagebox.Show("I am a \"Test\" Message.\r\nAm I working?");
```

and that works fine.

But now I add my message to a `Sql database` as an `nvarchar(max)` and retrive it from the database but now my messagebox shows everything including the \"

so when I do:

```
Messagebox.Show(databaseString)
```

It displays the literal string:

> I am a \"Test\" Message.\r\nAm I working?

Instead of:

> I am a "Test" Message.
>
> Am I working?"

How do I get rid of the `\"` and `\r\n` when I get my string from a database? Do I need to encode it?

PS. I don't want to use `String.Replace` as there could be more uses in the future i.e. `\t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(databaseString);
```

More info [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

What if you store it

```
string str = @"I am a ""Test"" Message." + Environment.NewLine + "Am I working?";
```

Comment: So I store the string `@"I am a ""Test"" Message." + Environment.NewLine + "Am I working?"` in my database? Are you sure that would work? Ive got a feeling it wouldn't work

Comment: @user1, not tested though but it should work. Idea is to use verbatim string literal and use framework provided newline syntax rather than hardcoding it. Give it a try and see.